# `pip install` under Ubuntu, works; fails under Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, lxml, python-docx

I've written a program and in order to help some colleagues of mine to install it in an easy way, I've built a python [package](https://pypi.org/project/taskAutom/).

In Ubuntu is fairly easy to install it. Just doing `pip3 install taskAutom` will do the job.

I've created myself a Win10 VM to test it under Windows, but I cannot install the package. I get an error which I still do not understand ... in the sense that I still don't know what to do to avoid it.

[image]

In my program I use `python-docx` which depends on `lxml`. Installing it using pip on windows, complains...

**UPDATE:**  I've found that using python3.8 solves the issue. For the original test, I used python3.11. Is not a bad workaround, but I'd like to be agnostic to the OS or Python Version.

Thanks.

Comment: Lately, there have been many questions about installing lxml on Windows.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5blxml%5d%20install

Comment: It's very weird. Under ubuntu, no problem, either using python3.8 or 3.10. But under win10, a lot of trouble. Had to downgrade python version to 3.8 in Win10, to make it work... clueless ...